# Is it correct to use the word " learn" in this sentence or better to use " teach"?

Tags: phrases, syntactic-analysis

"Animal learn us to never give up " ,
Or better to say "Animal teach us to never give up" ?

Comment: What is “ue”?..

Comment: Is it that the animals are learning something (first sentence) or that the animals are teaching us something (second sentence).  Since I have never heard of "ue" I cannot tell which of these is intended.

Comment: “Animal learn/teach” is never correct as subject + verb. It should either be “animals learn/teach” or “an/the animal learns/teaches”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exchange of "learn" and "teach" is often taken as a sign of a poor, rural education in the US. The subject of "learn" is the person/animal who is being given the knowledge/training, while the subject of "teach" is the person/thing supplying the knowledge/training.

Note that the object of "learn" is the topic being taught, while the object of "teach" can be either the topic or the entity that is (hopefully) learning.

Comment: _Teach_ is optionally ditransitive: the direct object is the subject taught, and the indirect object is the person learning the subject. Both are optional, but they can also occur (“She taught English” / “She taught me” / “She taught me English”). Some would argue that the indirect object is promoted to a direct object if the direct object is not present (I wouldn’t necessarily agree); see [this answer by tchrist](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/203147) for more.